# UseState is setting values only 2 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a basic dark mode react app. I have created an `onClick` function on button, but the `useState` hook is setting the value of appear object only 2 times.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const About = () => {
  const whitem = {
    color: "black",
    backgroundColor : "white"
  }
  const darkm = {
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor : "black"
  }

  const [appear, setAppear] = useState(whitem)
  const [btntext, setBtntext] = useState('Enable dark mode')

  const btn_handler = () => {
    console.log("button clicked")
    if (appear === whitem) {
      setAppear(darkm)
      setBtntext('Enable white mode')
    } else {
      setAppear(whitem)
      setBtntext('Enable dark mode')
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='container my-4' style={appear}>
      <h2 style={appear}>Heading</h2>
      <p style={appear}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. In, et. At officiis aliquam quidem, nihil est consectetur quas perferendis a quibusdam porro ex nesciun
      </p>
      <button
        onClick={btn_handler}
        type='button'
        className='btn btn-dark my-4'
      >
        {btntext}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have tried checked wheather the onclick function is called on not using console.log. But the appear object value is set only 2 times and not further.

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison is based on `whitem` and `darkm`. However, you recreate both on each render, so `appear === whitem` is never `true`.

Move both objects out of the `About` component:

```
const whitem = {
  color: "black",
  backgroundColor : "white"
}
const darkm = {
  color: "white",
  backgroundColor : "black"
}

export const About = () => {
```

Working example:

```js
const { useState } = React

const lightm = { color: "black", backgroundColor : "white" }
const darkm = { color: "white", backgroundColor : "black" }

const About = () => {
  const [appear, setAppear] = useState(lightm)
  
  const toggleAppear = () => {
    setAppear(prev => prev === lightm ? darkm : lightm)
  }

  return (
    <div className='container my-4' style={appear}>
      <h2 style={appear}>Heading</h2>
      <p style={appear}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. In, et. At officiis aliquam quidem, nihil est consectetur quas perferendis a quibusdam porro ex nesciun</p>
      <button 
        onClick={toggleAppear} 
        type='button' 
        className='btn btn-dark my-4'>
        Enable {appear === lightm ? 'dark' : 'light'} mode
        </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<About />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```